# Input not updating on changing variable value

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

i am using updated hook to update another wire:model value, if i dd or print the variable in the view i can see updated value but not in input itself
Same logic was working file on livewire 2
codes

```
{{ $customerCode }}

<input wire:model.live="customerCode" type="text" id="customer_code" name="customer_code" class="form-control" placeholder="" />

<input type="text" wire:model.blur="name" class="form-control" placeholder="John Doe"/> 
{{-- on changing this it run a updatedName hook runs and i can seed printed on view on above $customerCode but on in input --}}
```

Component Code

```
public function updatedName(){
    $this->customerCode =  'random string';//generateUniqueUserCode($this->name);
}
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Hi, you might be receiving downvotes because your question is not clear. I would start by using normal [interpunction](https://www.ef.co.uk/english-resources/english-grammar/punctuation/), check the spelling, and don't start with the vague: _"this thing"_. The code and illustration aren't very clear either. I know, we could guess a lot, but that's not the point. You should try to make the life of the people who can help you as easy as possible. Preferably with a working [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Okay i am editing. But the issue is very short i want to update another model on update first model , it is updating but not reflecting on input itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this complete example:

**Component Class**

```php
public function updating($property, $value) // invoked this every time you update the $property model
{
    if($property === "name") {
        $this->customerCode = generateUniqueUserCode($this->name);
        // change the 'customerCode' just before updating the 'name' model.
    }
}
```

**Component Blade**

```html
<!--- notice the absence of 'wire:model' attribut on the first input.  --->
<input  
  id="customer_code"
  name="customer_code"
  class="form-control"
  placeholder=""
  type="text"
  value="{{ $customerCode }}"
/>

<input
  class="form-control"
  placeholder="John Doe"
  type="text"
  wire:model.blur="name"
/>
```

since the first input value is not a wire-model, you're sure that only one javascript code is controlling it.
hope you find this useful, I try it on my local and it works!

Comment: Could you add an explanation next to the "try this" part? What does your code do? Why did you solve it this way?

Answer (score 1):

I think I understood what you want to do, you may misunderstand the role of **live model**:

1. It does not import the value stored in your server-side value in the component (even after being changed in server-side), it rather waits client to change its value, againt, without looking out its old value.
2. Moreover, if a **blur model** is modified by user, and you set an updated/updating hook triggered when you update this blur-modal, and changing the other component properties, **live model**  are still not not capable to be updated on the client-side.

I suggest that you abondon puting customerCode inside live-modal, print it simply as a text, since it's not up to the user to generate their code.

```html
<input
  id="customer_code"
  name="customer_code"
  class="form-control"
  placeholder=""
  type="text"
  value="{{ $customerCode }}"
/>
```

Comment: you are right by setting value to the variable the input value gets updated if i inspect, but the text dosen't get updated it still shows blank text ,
previously in livewire 3 if i update wire:model variable value server side it automatically reflects on input client side, but in livewire 3 it is not happening, can you reproduce same scenario from your side and check

Comment: Effectively, it's a little bit weird, livewire is still under progress, and thinks change significantely after updates.

Comment: actually the p[roblem was i loaded alpine manually wheras livewire 3 already bundled with alpine js, your solution and removing loading of alpine from app.js both worked